# Error: Persistent store migration failed, missing source managed object model.

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm getting the following message error:

> Error: Persistent store migration failed, missing source managed
>   object model.

I've copied a xCode project from the company mac to my mac (same configuration: Snow Leopard, XCode 3.2

```
I've cleaned the project, 
deleted the build folder in finder, 
deleted Library/Application support/myApp folder
deleted Library/Preferences/MyApp...plist file
```

I still get the error. What's wrong with it ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quit the XCode Completely and reopen Xcode